# dothtml page with errors is showing as a completely blank page

Tags: dotvvm

when I run dothtml pages out of Visual Studio 2022 that may include a front-end error (for example there's a viewmodel value call on a dot:textbox that doesn't exist) the page simply returns a blank page with no content whatsoever. I used to get the dotvvm debugging page that would indicate an error.

I'm running VS v17.3.6 along with DOTVVM extension v4.0.552.0 and have tried updating both with no success, and have tried uninstalling and re-installing the DOTVVM extension. I am in the process of migrating my webforms over to dothtml so am running in OWIN. Could there be any other asp / c# nuget packages playing into this? Some were updated recently. Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: What is the version of DotVVM NuGet package installed in the project? We had a bug in some of the previous versions that caused this behavior.

Comment: Hi Tomas, I have the following: DotVVM 4.0.3, DotVVM.Contrib.Select2 4.01, DotVVM.Controls.Bootstrap4 4.0.5, DotVVM.Core 4.0.3, DotVVM.Owin 3.2.3. Here's a list of all Nuget packages in my project: https://www.adelaidetkd.com.au/docs/nuget.html

Comment: DotVVM.Owin should have the same version as DotVVM, so please try to upgrade it to 4.0.3.

Comment: Also, you can try to look in the Startup.cs file and see the AddDotVVM method - there is some isDebug flag or something. You can try to configure it so it will be true in DEBUG build. 
You can add a method like this to determine what to pass in the debug parameter:

 private bool IsInDebugMode()
        {
#if !DEBUG
   return false;
#endif
            return true;
        }

Comment: Thanks Tomas, upgrading the DotVVM.Owin package to 4.0.3 fixed it up!